# In an XNA game object, what should I use to represent a texture for serialization?

Tags: xna, c#

While trying to save to a file a list of objects needed to run my game, I noticed that `Texture2D` is not serializable. Why? What was the purpose?

The object I want to serialize looks like this:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class GameObject
{
    private Vector2 position_ = Vector2.Zero;
    private float rotation_ = 0.0f;
    private Vector2 scale_ = Vector2.One;
    private float depth_ = 0.0f;

    private Texture2D texture_;

    private bool is_passable_ = true;

    private GameObject(
        Vector2 starting_position,
        string filepath,
        ContentManager content)
    {
        this.position_ = starting_position;
        this.texture_ = Content.Load<Texture2D>(filepath);
    }

    //Properties
    //Update/Draw
}
```

So, what should I serialized since `Texture2D` isn't made to be used that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should serialize a *reference to* the texture (such as its file name), not the texture itself. That way when you load the serialized game object later, you know which texture to look up and associate with the object.

You don't want to serialize the entire texture with the object, because that would be a huge waste of space when objects started to share textures (when serialized, they'd each have a complete copy of the texture bytes). That's why the `Texture2D` object itself isn't marked as serializable. It's trying to protect you from yourself.

This is related to why it's generally a good idea to separate game logic state from rendering and visual presentation state.

Comment: One tip it to see the object constructor. You see that you only need the starting position and the `filepath`.

Comment: @GustavoMaciel Maciel Should I add a "filename" private field for every GameObject, serialize it and then while deserializing reload the texture using that filename?

Comment: @JoshPetrie In this simple case, what does it mean "separate game logic state from..."? Does it mean that the texture shouldn't be inside my GameObject class? Can please give me a simple pattern to show that?

Comment: At the basic level it means to keep anything directly render-related (like texture objects) out of your game logic classes. Have separate objects for rendering things, and at the top level of your game, facilitate the transfer of data between the two. It's a broad topic and you should be able to find many resources on such a *separation of concerns* by searching.